# Conversion 0-20mA to 0-5V

Tags: 4-20ma

Have you ever used this device? https://fluxworkshop.com/products/biaa100070-lm358-a2v-20ma-5v-lc-blue

I have prepared a circuit as follows.

[image]

I have used a distance sensor. Unfortunately, I obtain a constant value of 10-12 V in the VOUT. That value doesn't depend on the distance, only on a potentiometer value. What did I do wrong?

Comment: This makes no sense. The module you linked has nothing to do with your circuit? It is an LM358 based current to voltage converter. If your schematic is supposed to show this, then you are missing out the rest of the circuitry on the module. Please link some datasheets, some module schematics or more information, otherwise this is all guesswork as to what you did wrong

Comment: Is your distance sensor actually a two wire sensor, or does it require a ground?

Comment: A simple 250 ohm resistor would do what you appear to want.

Comment: Have you measured the voltage applied at Cin to ground? Looks from the board like the sense resistor is the 100 ohm bottom left, so you should be seeing 0.4 to 2.0V across the input terminals.

Comment: @Andyaka where should I plug the resistor? Between CIN and GND?

Comment: Please post this question to Fluxworkshop.  EE.SE isn't their volunteer technical support.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fClZKM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A 0 to 20 mA to 0 to 5 V conversion can be done with a single resistor.*